# Prevent stubbing of equals method

Tags: methods, mocking, mockito, equals, stub

I would like to test my class' equals() method but Mockito seems to be calling the stub version every time. My test is as follows;

```
PluginResourceAdapter adapter = mock (PluginResourceAdapter.class);
PluginResourceAdapter other = mock (PluginResourceAdapter.class);

when(adapter.getNumberOfEndpointActivation()).thenReturn(1);
when(other.getNumberOfEndpointActivation()).thenReturn(0);

boolean result = adapter.equals(other);
assertFalse(result);
```

I know I cannot stub the equals method which means Mockito should be calling my real implementation but its not.

I have also tried this:

```
when (adapter.equals(any()).thenCallRealMethod()
```

but I get the same result.

Comment: Mockito automatically overrides `equals` with its own implementation, so that it can find a mock in its internal structures (`HashMap`s or `TreeMap`s I think) when it needs to record that a method has been called on a mock.  This is fundamental to the way it works, which is why it doesn't allow you to provide your own `equals`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even beyond [Mockito's limitations](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito), it doesn't make much sense for a mocked object to use a real `equals` method, if for no other reason than that equals methods almost always use fields, and mocked objects never run any of their constructors or field initializers.

Also, be aware of what you're testing: In a test of `Foo`, ideally you should never mock `Foo`, even to set up a `Foo` to compare against. Otherwise, it's easy to inadvertently test that Mockito works, rather than testing your own component's logic.

You have a few workarounds:

- As Garrett Hall mentioned, create real objects. This may require factoring out the "data objects" from the services that use them, and mocking the services while using real data objects. This is probably a good idea overall.
- Create a manual mock or fake by subclassing PluginResourceAdapter or implementing the relevant interface outside of Mockito. This frees you to define all methods as needed, including `equals` and `hashCode`.
- Create an `equivalentTo` method, which isn't the same as `equals` (and thus isn't as useful for Map or Set objects, for instance) but that has mockable semantics you can define on your own.

  This would also let you test `equivalentTo` freely with a mock, and simply have `equals` delegate to that presumably-well-tested implementation.
- Extract an object that tests equality, and mock that. You could also use [Guava's `Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) there, or a `Comparator` where you test `a.compareTo(b) == 0`.

  ```
  class YourClass {
    class AdapterEquivalence {
      boolean adaptersAreEqual(
          PluginResourceAdapter a, PluginResourceAdapter b) {
        return a.equals(b);
      }
    }

    /** Visible for testing. Replace in tests. */
    AdapterEquivalence adapterEquivalence = new AdapterEquivalence();
  }
  ```

Note that one other potential workaround—[spying on existing instances](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)—will also [redefine `equals` and `hashCode`](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=241) and won't help you here.

Comment: I used Second option i.e. @OVerriden the methods required mocking and used the real objec.equals(object). Thanks

Comment: @Jeff Although this is usual : `it doesn't make much sense for a mocked object to use a real equals method, if for no other reason than that equals methods almost always use fields, and mocked objects never run any of their constructors or field initializers`, the equals implementation is free to use the getters instead of fields. So I don't think this would be a justification for mockito to not allow stubbing of equals/hashcode

Comment: @Dhiraj Or it could not use fields at all, for pure Singleton objects. Even if there are remote cases where this could make sense, I hope you agree that the limitations would make it hard to prioritize this case over other useful development.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test the *real* `equals` then you need to create a *real* object and call the `equals` method on it.  I'm not sure why you are using mocks.

Answer (score 0):

By default equals() returns true if object have the same address in memory.
So 
`PluginResourceAdapter adapter; 
 PluginResourceAdapter other; 
 adapter = other = mock (PluginResourceAdapter.class);`

returns true to you. If you want false use
`PluginResourceAdapter adapter = mock (PluginResourceAdapter.class);
 PluginResourceAdapter other   = mock (PluginResourceAdapter.class);`

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the original question.