# How to mock the Android Signature class equals() method using Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I am using `Signature` class `equlas()` method to compare two signature objects in my class.

```
for (Signature allowedSignature : storedSignature) {
                if (allowedSignature.equals(signature)) {
                    return true;
                }
   }
```

I have written test cases using Mockito to test the above code block. I need to Mock the `Signature` class and `equals()`method.

```
    Signature signature = PowerMockito.mock(Signature.class);
    when(signature.equals((Signature)notNull())).thenReturn(true);
```

So I have implemented like mentioned above, but I am getting error like this,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

Comment: As you can see in [Mockito's limitations](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ) it cannot mock `equals` method. If you want to go in depth with this, you could have a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778592/prevent-stubbing-of-equals-method), There is a really good answer on it.

Comment: @troig Thanks for the compliment! :) OP: Marking this a duplicate; you'll need to figure out another strategy to produce equal objects for test.